# css expression not work for primefaces

Tags: java, css, jsf-2, primefaces

Below code not work, but it's work fine for jsf1.2.
Now the framework is jsf2.0 and primefaces 3.2

```
<p:inputText id="pInputText4"  disabled="true" value="This is Input
Text" style="color:
expression((this.disabled==true)?'#0f0':'#f00');"/>
```

I have another question that why

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="roleId" value="#{accessPage.roleId}" required="true">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.common.selecthere']}" itemValue="#{null}" />
   <f:selectItems var="code" value="#{accessPage.roleIdList}"   
       itemLabel="#{code.codeDesc}" itemValue="#{code.codeId}" />
   <f:valueChangeListener type="com.ncs.caseconnect.base.app.utils.ValueChangeCleanUtils"/>
   <p:ajax listener="#{accessPage.roleOrModuleChanged}" update="accessRight" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

the valueChangeListener and ajax not work when we select the first null option. If we remove the required attribute it works fine. Is it conflict between required and valueChangeListener?

Comment: tested it against `h:inputText`JSF2 seems to work.Not tried for Primefaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#{component}` in any of the component's attributes to get hold of the concrete `UIComponent` instance of the current component. This resolves in case of `<p:inputText>` to an instance of [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) which in turn has a `boolean disabled` property. So, this should do:

```html
<p:inputText id="pInputText4" disabled="true" value="This is Input Text" 
    style="color: #{component.disabled ? '#0f0' : '#f00'};" />
```

But a better practice is to define styling in a CSS file instead of straight in the markup as it eliminates duplication and maintenance headache.

```html
<p:inputText id="pInputText4" disabled="true" value="This is Input Text" 
    styleClass="foo" />
```

with

```css
.foo {
    color: #f00;
}

.foo[disabled] {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

Or if you want to apply this globally on all input elements

```html
<p:inputText id="pInputText4" disabled="true" value="This is Input Text" />
```

with

```css
input {
    color: #f00;
}

input[disabled] {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: Hi BalusC: why the first solution is not work fine in css file. I want to add color: #{component.disabled and component.disabled==true and component.type=='text' ? '#0f0' : '#f00'} in css file ,but it not work. The preview work fine in style attribute. Can you give me another suggestion?

Comment: The `#{component}` is only available **inside** the component itself, not in the CSS file. It has also no `type` property at all. You're perhaps confusing with JavaScript. I'd suggest to use the latter approach. You can select `input type="text" disabled="true"` with this selector `input[type=text][disabled] {}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have another question about <p:selectonemenu>,can you help to view it? It is added in the top content.

Comment: You're welcome. As to the new question, please press `Ask Question` on right top, don't reuse an existing question for this. One question per question, please :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess that eventually you will use `disabled="#{someBean.someCondition}"`

and in this case you will have to use EL expression in your `style` too m like this

```
<p:inputText id="pInputText4"  disabled="#{someBean.someCondition}" value="This is Input
    Text" style="color:#{someBean.someCondition ?'#0f0':'#f00'}"/>
```

Dunno about the `expression` but are you sure that you can access `this` and that `this.disabled` really gives you the value of your `disabled` attribute ? (try displaying it in `alert(this.disabled)`)