# Checking with css if JSF inputText is required

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2

here my code:
The xhtml Page:

```
<p:inputText required="true" value="#{bean.name}" />
```

And the css code:

```
input:focus{
        border-color: #5D8DC5;
}

input:focus:required:invalid:focus{
    border-color: #e9322d;
}
```

The application should color the border of the inputText red if nothing is written and it is focused. And if something is written the inputText should be colored automatically blue. With simple html it would be easy:

```
<input type="text " name="name" required="true" />
```

How can check this in css with an jsf component like p:inputText?

Comment: So the following works: http://jsfiddle.net/9pL77/ (which is just your bits pieced together). Is your problem that you don't want that logic to apply to all inputs? Primefaces is just generating HTML for you. You can apply css on that normally.

Comment: @mabi: JSF `required` attribute != HTML5 `required` attribute. OP however incorrectly assumed/expected that.

Comment: @BalusC eww, you're right, the spec never said JSF's required to add this to the HTML. I never noticed that. @Hege Guess your options are either [passthrough attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/p/_.html) or a custom `styleClass` you can check in your CSS. Neither is pretty :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very clear in this area but it did spark some interest and after searching around, I found someone who had a similar issue.

It seems that to style JSF components, you should assign it a styleClass and refer to the style class in your css, like you would a normal tag that had a defined class.

Hope this gives you some direction.

Sources/examples:
[How apply CSS on a <h:inputText>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789977/how-apply-css-on-a-hinputtext)
[css expression not work for primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991576/css-expression-not-work-for-primefaces)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward; using EL, evaluate the bean value and set the `style` property:

```
<p:inputText required="true" value="#{bean.name}" style="color: #{bean.name == null ? 'red' : 'blue'};"/>
```

Here the EL contains a ternary operator, the result of which evaluates to the CSS `color` property.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "changing from red to blue" and the "focused" part, which are hard to do in EL since they're client only.